# How to get the simplexmlelement attributes values using php?

Tags: php, xml, svg

I have `simplexml` element object which is rendered output of foreach results. I have to extract the value from the output.

So far I tried to loop the `simplexmlelement` objects. I am forming the `svg` elements from the given output. Those output are from the another `foreach` loop results.

```
[g] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 0.2922376764472574
                )

            [text] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [fill] => #000000
                            [stroke] => none
                            [stroke-width] => 0
                            [stroke-linecap] => round
                            [stroke-linejoin] => round
                            [x] => 65
                            [y] => 85
                            [text-anchor] => middle
                            [font-size] => 90.75
                            [font-family] => Twine
                            [data-textcurve] => 0
                            [data-itemzoom] => 1 1
                        )

                    [tspan] => Tetst
                )

        )


for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++)
            {
                //var_dump( $result[$i] );
                //$op .= '<g id="0.8354780427180231">';

                print_r($result[$i]);

                echo "testsdf";print_r($result[$i]->g['text']);

                echo 'test<g id="'.$result[$i]->g['id'].'"><text fill="'.$result[$i]->text->attributes()->fill.'" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="65" y="85" text-anchor="middle" font-size="90.75" font-family="Twine" data-textcurve="0" data-itemzoom="1 1">'.$result[$i]->text['tspan'].'</text>';

                echo "</g>";
                echo $result[$i]->g->text['font-family'];

            }
```

Comment: Just add what happens when you try the above code. Do you get any error? You dont get the elements you want but it runs?

Comment: It would be easier if you shared the original XML rather than a dump of the SimpleXMLElement object.

Answer (score 0):

A small example of how to use the structure and accessing various parts of the document using SimpleXML.

```
<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );

$html = "<body>
<g id='0.2922376764472574'>
<text fill='#000000' stroke='none' stroke-width='0'>
<tspan>Tetst</tspan>
</text>
</g>
</body>";

$doc = simplexml_load_string($html);

foreach ( $doc->g as $tag)  {
    echo "<g id='".$tag['id']."'>";   
    echo "<text fill='".$tag->text['fill']."'>";
    echo $tag->text->tspan;
    echo "</text>";
    echo "</g>";
}
```

I've had to make assumptions about your XML content, but I hope this is near enough.

I'm basing it around looping through all  tags off the root of the document.  If this isn't the case you can change this to...

```
foreach ($result as $tag)
```

which should do the same thing if your (for example) fetching these from an XPath query.

I've taken out some of the attributes, but it's just a case of repeating the same logic, accessing each attribute as though it was an associative array element.

The output from the test sample is...

```
<g id='0.2922376764472574'><text fill='#000000'>Tetst</text></g>
```